# Spark view engine and ASP.NET MVC 2 strongly Typed Html Helpers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I try to use HtmlHelper.TextBoxFor with spark view engine but view crashed with exception "Dynamic view compilation failed.  'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'TextBoxFor' and no extension method 'TextBoxFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

It is my _global.spark:

```
<use namespace="System"/>
<use namespace="System.Linq"/>
<use namespace="System.Text" />
<use namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
<use namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
<use namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
<use namespace="System.Linq.Expressions" />
<use namespace="MyModels" />
```

In spark-view using:
`${Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)}`

Comment: Which Spark version do you use? Was it compiled using MVC 2? Please update it to newest version.

Answer (score 1):

I use the newest version of spark. I found what was wrong. I miss to add model type in view.

```
<viewdata model=MyModel"/>
```